# Sep and End Arguments in print() statement

Tags: python-3.9, separator

I am currently using Python 3.9.6 version and while using the print() statement with "sep=" as an argument, i am getting the syntax error.

My code for "Sep" Argument is:
print("John","Sam","Michael",sep="-")

My code for "End" Argument is:
print("John","Sam","Michael",end="-")

I don't understand what's the problem with my code. Please help

Please find the attached snippet of both the codes:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRPKY.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ep5ZU.png)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please provide the entire traceback and relevant code. There is nothing wrong with the `print` statement, so the syntax error must be coming from somewhere else

Comment: There is no `print` in those screenshots.

Comment: Actually I am using IDLE's interactive mode and for it to work you don't need to use print statement. You can only get the output by just hitting enter.

Comment: There is a difference between using `print` to write to standard output and letting the interpreter output the result of an *expression*. You are trying to assign a tuple to a name with a malformed expression.

Comment: `print(x, sep="-")` is not just a keyword followed by a tuple; it's a function call, the syntax of which allows keyword arguments. Expression lists do *not*.

Comment: This would have been obvious to everyone had you actually reproduced the code in your screen shot as text, rather than misleading everyone with code that does *not* produce a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
print("John","Sam","Michael",sep,"=","-")
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error

Comment: I have made the changes in the code, can you please check it

Answer (score 0):

Try using `end`.

Ex: `print("John","Sam","Michael",end="-")`

Comment: I just want to separate th output with hyphen in it like this: John-Sam-Michael

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: Can you please check the edited code

Comment: It's weird because `print("John","Sam","Michael",sep="-")` works can you post the output image of `print("John","Sam","Michael",sep="-")` statement. 
From you image you can even do something like this
`a="-".join(('10','20','30'))`
and then print(a)
note this only works for set of strings

Comment: I have posted the new image please check

Comment: This a="-".join(('10','20','30')) code worked, thanks!!!

Comment: Would you be able to figure out why my code wasn't working

Comment: Well, In the statement `a=(10,20,30,sep='-')` you are trying to assign a tuple to variable `a`. A tuple doesn't have the attribute `sep` so it does not work. Whereas in the solution `a="-".join(('10','20','30'))` you are creating a tuple, converting it into string by joining elements using `-`. `print("John","Sam","Michael",sep="-")` also works but you are not printing the result.

Comment: Yes, you are right, this time I just written the print("John","Sam","Michael",sep="-") statement only without storing this into any variable and it worked. Thanks for helping me in understanding this issue.